# How is an RCD snubber different from an RC low pass filter?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, low-pass, snubber

The RCD snubber is used in flyback SMPS designs where AC-DC conversion is carried out. I know that a snubber circuit is used; its purpose is to filter transients. According to my understanding, the transients are high-frequency noise ripples.

My question is, why do we need to use an RCD snubber rather than a simple RC or LC low-pass filter?

Answer (score 3):

When a N-Channel MOSFET is switched "off" at a high switching speed, the result is an abrupt change in the current flowing in the circuit from the "on" current to basically zero.  Since voltage on an inductor is L*di/dt, this rapid change in current results in high voltages occurring from any stray inductance in the current path.  Depending on the quality of the board layout and transformer design, the voltage may be many times higher than the supply voltage.  The energy in the stray inductance must be dissipated, and if no snubber is present, the voltage can go up until the MOSFET peak voltage is reached, causing it to zener and the MOSFET dissipates the energy.

The purpose of the snubber is to provide a load to dissipate this energy away from the switching element.  The capacitor provides a current path through the diode so that di/dt is reduced, and the current from the stray inductances charge the capacitor to a higher voltage (but not too high!).  Then the resistor can discharge it between pulses, with the energy going into heat in the resistor.

Without the diode, the capacitive load would always be present, causing high currents when the MOSFET is switched "on".  RCD snubbers are usually biased to the supply voltage, so that only voltages exceeding the supply voltage present a load to the transients.

So in general, an RC network is used for signal conditioning, while an RCD snubber is used for power conditioning.

Comment: Would an actual diode be used for this or a transistor connected into diode configuration?

Comment: Use fast switching diodes.  Make sure you have a good snubber layout (no long or narrow traces)  in addition to your good power supply layout.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to use the correct terminology when describing an electrical circuit though, very often, the term *snubber* generically appears in all the below descriptions. In my opinion, there are three different terms for describing these \$RC\$ associations:

The \$RCD\$ clamp: this is a true hard clamp, it is there to limit the voltage excursion across the opening MOSFET in a flyback converter for example. The resistor dissipates the power stored in the leakage inductance with some smaller part in the magnetizing inductance. The capacitor reduces the ripple across the resistor and they both form a low-impedance dc source, hard-clamping the drain excursion above the high-voltage rail.

[image]

You can find design examples in many sources such as in my APEC 2011 seminar, *[The Dark Side of the Flyback Converter](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf)*.

A \$RC\$ damper: as the name implies, a \$RC\$ damper is there to *damp* or increase the damping ratio of an oscillatory circuit. How do you do this? By dissipating power cycle by cycle.

[image]

You see how the blocking diode excites the \$LC\$ parasitic network made of the secondary-side leakage inductance and the diode parasitic capacitance (plus of course all the PCB contributors on top). It rings and has deleterious effects on radiated EMI, especially if the loop involving the diode is wide. To damp these oscillations, a resistance is calculated to sufficiently dissipate/damp the oscillations while the capacitor stops the dc component and also helps find a trade-off between the reduction in oscillation amplitude and the impact on the overall efficiency as these dampers can heat up quite a bit.

The \$RC\$ snubber: in the previous applications, the resistance was having the main role - dissipating power - while the capacitor was an "assistant" (reduce ripple in the \$RCD\$ clamp and limit dissipation in the \$RC\$ damper). Here, the capacitor is present for delaying the rise of the drain-source voltage at the switch opening:

[image]

You see that without it, there is an overlap between the drain current and the voltage across the transistor, leading to a high turn-off loss, scaled by the switching frequency. By adding a capacitor, the current initially circulating in the transistor is diverted in the capacitor that it needs to charge (it is at 0 V when the switch opens) and it delays the rise of the drain-source voltage. As the switch is turned off quickly, the drain current has been switched off while the voltage was only starting to rise. As a result, the overlap in the second figure has almost disappeared, leading to reduced turn-off losses. A resistor is added to limit the turn-on loss occurring when the switch turns back on (the capacitor you've added is now fully charged) and the dissipation budget is diverted in the resistor. But this resistor also defeats the capacitor action so you can short it at the switch opening with a diode as shown in the right side of the picture.

As usual, trade offs are necessary between the need to limit the switching loss on the active components and the power you accept to dissipate externally.